# Installing Xubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows, can't disable secure boot, GRUB not showing

Tags: xubuntu, uefi, grub-legacy

I recently installed Xubuntu version 16.04 by using Legacy mode. UEFI was not working because it had secure boot enabled, and it was not an option to turn off secure boot.
If I tried to boot from my usb with Xubuntu on it, it would show that there was a security boot error. Instead, I switched over to legacy mode and I booted from the usb without problems and installed on empty partitions I made earlier.

Now when I boot up it goes directly to Xubuntu (still in Legacy). However, when I remove the usb drive with Xubuntu on it, it doesn't load anything. My question is, why doesn't the GRUB menu show up? Is this a restriction in Legacy mode?
[Here is boot info](http://www.paste2.org/5fC7Jm1y)

Comment: If I get you right GRUB is on the usb ? if so then it won't boot.

Comment: I would advise to read thru your BIOS documentation or manual and go for UEFI with secure boot/fast boot disabled. I had troubles with my HP desktop for that initially but i figured it out.

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to allow users to turn off UEFI Secure boot except some now old Windows RT systems. But you still should be able to boot Ubuntu with Secure boot on. But then cannot dual boot from grub menu only UEFI boot menu. You can only dual boot from grub menu with Secure boot off and systems installed in same boot mode, both UEFI or both BIOS. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: In response to the second comment, there is no option in the bios to disable fast boot. @oldfred The link for the BootInfo summary report is: http://www.paste2.org/5fC7Jm1y

Comment: You have an Acer, which requires you to enable a UEFI supervisory password and enable "trust" from UEFI to .efi files in ESP. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot You have installed grub in BIOS boot mode, but if you boot Boot-Repair in UEFI mode you can use its advanced mode to convert to UEFI boot.  You also converted sdb to SFS or dynamic partitions. One of the worst things you can do even if just only a Windows user. You need to use Windows tools to convert. Boot-Repair report mentions one.

Comment: Ok, any tips on how to proceed? For now I'm installing the boot-repair-disk onto a usb, I'll first try the method you send from the link to allow Ubuntu to be trusted for executing in UEFI. Also, when converting the SFS to basic, do I need to do this from Windows? Thank you so much for the advice.

Comment: Update: I set a password for security, now I have option to turn off secure boot. I will attempt to install Xubuntu regularly from UEFI, then I will reconfigure that SFS partition to be basic.